# Wordpress - Count posts for each year

Tags: wordpress, count, archive

I'm using the following code to list all years from my blog, I guess we can call it an archive.

```
<?php
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($years as $year) : ?>
    <?php echo $year ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I'd like to achieve though is to also display, in front of each year, the number of posts (count) that each year has. Example:

```
2015 (5 posts)
2014 (3 posts)
2011 (10 posts)
```

I found a hint somewhere and tried to implement it, but didn't work. Here's what I was trying:

```
<?php
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY post_date DESC");
$count = $years->post_count;
foreach($years as $year) : ?>
    <?php echo $year ?> (<?php echo $count ?> posts)
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not simply use something like [wp_get_archives('type=yearly');](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives)?

Comment: No, I really need to "decompose" the output code. E.g. I want to give the numbers a special class.

Comment: Fixed at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178816/count-posts-for-each-year

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using

```
    <?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
echo $count_posts->publish;
?>
```

You can also look into [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It's counting the posts from all years. Tried something like `<?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts($year); echo $count_posts->publish ?>` but that doesn't work. Inside `wp_count_posts();` should go the post type. I kinda feel limited.